# How to instantly update react state after replacing the value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, indexof

I have a function which gets the user input and update the array if the same key is available already. with the help of this [article](https://herewecode.io/blog/replace-item-array-javascript/)

This is how it looks;

```
  const handleClickYes = (question) => {
    // find if question is in the data array
    const hasQuestion = data.find(({ parentId }) => question.id === parentId)
    
    const indexOfQuestion = data.indexOf(hasQuestion)
    
    if (hasQuestion) {
      // update the value with specific selected index in the array. 
      data[indexOfQuestion] = { question: question.if_yes, parentId: question.id, userChoice: 'YES', child: [] }
    } else {
      setData((data) => data.concat({ question: question.if_yes, parentId: question.id, userChoice: 'YES', child: [] }))
    }
    localStorage.setItem('deviceReport', JSON.stringify(data))
  }
```

I'm using localStorage to persist the state

```
  const deviceReport = localStorage.getItem('deviceReport') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('deviceReport')) : []
  const [data, setData] = useState(deviceReport)
```

Here the problem is if I use setData then it updates instantly but on replacing the array
at this part

```
data[indexOfQuestion] = { question: question.if_yes, parentId: question.id, userChoice: 'YES', child: [] }
```

it dosent update the mapped data on JSX portion. How can I configure it to update it happen in setState. ? Or any other better option to update the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `setState()` within the first half of your `if` block. Also, [never mutate state directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760774/2103784). Make a mutable copy, like so:

```js
const handleClickYes = (question) => {
  // find if question is in the data array
  const hasQuestion = data.find(({ parentId }) => question.id === parentId);

  const indexOfQuestion = data.indexOf(hasQuestion);

  // copy data to mutable object
  let newData = [...data];
  if (hasQuestion) {
    // update the value with specific selected index in the array.
    newData[indexOfQuestion] = {
      question: question.if_yes,
      parentId: question.id,
      userChoice: "YES",
      child: [],
    };
  } else {
    //   concat existing data with a new question
    newData = [
      ...newData,
      {
        question: question.if_yes,
        parentId: question.id,
        userChoice: "YES",
        child: [],
      },
    ];
  }
  localStorage.setItem("deviceReport", JSON.stringify(newData));
  setData(newData);
};
```